# Using os.system() in Python is open a program, can't see window of launched program

Tags: python, os.system

I am trying to launch a program/GUI from within a python code.

From the terminal, I can get the program to launch by simply typing the program name. A few lines get outputted to the terminal, and then a separate window opens with the GUI.

I tried to emulate this in python by running

```
os.system("<program name>")
```

The typical output lines, as mentioned above, get printed to the console, but no window opens up with the GUI.

Can os.system() be used to execute programs that have their own separate window?

Comment: Take a look into the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module for more flexible process creation.

Comment: I just ran `os.system('subl test.txt')` and it opened the GUI just like normal. Running Python 3.5.1 on Windows 10, for reference. Though I may be misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system):

> [[`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system)] is implemented by calling the Standard C function
>   [`system()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system)

That being said, you shouldn't have any problems launching a GUI application with [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system). I've just tried it myself and it works fine.

It also mentions in the manual that:

> The [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module provides more powerful facilities for spawning
>   new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is
>   preferable to using this function.

Maybe that's worth a try. Do any other GUI applications work when you spawn them with [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system)?

Comment: Looks like this may be related to a larger (more scary) problem, as suddenly I can't load the program at all (among other important problems, such as not being able to any new files or load nautilus). Thanks though, I'll know it should work now!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `subprocess`

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("notepad.exe")
```

Or if you want to run a python program with a specific interpreter:

```
subprocess.Popen('{0} {1}'.format(PythonInterpreterPath,PythonFilePath.py))
```